# EO WebBrowser Page cache issue

Tags: c#, .net, eo.webbrowser

I am using a EO webView inside a windows from to load an HTML page. The page seems to cache even though I am using the following in the page. How can I make sure the page loads with a hard refresh each time?

I have added a context menu item in the windows form for "PageRefresh", so it runs `CommandIds.ReloadNoCache` on selecting the menu item. How do I make is to happen on Page Load.

```html
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I have the following code to add a menu item to do the PageRefresh, which works fine, but I want it to happen with user triggering the menu item.

```html
private void WebView_BeforeContextMenu(object sender, BeforeContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    e.Menu.Items.Clear();

    e.Menu.Items.Add(new EO.WebBrowser.MenuItem("ViewSource", CommandIds.ViewSource));

    e.Menu.Items.Add(new EO.WebBrowser.MenuItem("PageRefresh", CommandIds.ReloadNoCache));

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [EO admin response](http://www.essentialobjects.com/forum/postst8926_Clear-Cached-browser-page.aspx)

> In the current version the only way to clear cache is seems to delete
>   the EO.WebBrowser.Runtime.CachePath directory. You will need to close
>   all WebView instances in order to do so. In the future we will add
>   some interface for you to clear cache programmatically without having
>   to shutdown all WebViews.

Comment: Thank you for you response.